# filter items from an array of javascript objects

Tags: arrays, lodash, javascript-objects

I have a map of the form,

```
var map1 = {123 : true, 345: false, 456:true} ; where 123, 345, 456 are ids with status 'true' or 'false'.
```

Now, based on the boolean status of the ids above, I need to remove the records of those ids from the below array,

```
                [ {
                    id:123,
                    name:'foo'

               },
               {
                    id:345,
                    name:'baar'

               },{
                    id:456,
                    name:'foobar'

               }]
```

So, in this example, the objects with ids '121' and '456' should be deleted as they are with boolean status 'true' in the map.

Comment: Have you tried anything? I'm not sure what the problem is.

Comment: Object with id 121 wont be deleted from the table, since you've set 123 to true in map, 121 is not set to any value

Comment: Thanks @Septuagint, it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Given that your map is called `map1` and your array you need to filter is called `arr` this should do the trick:
`arr.filter((elem) => { return !map1[elem.id] }`

Comment: A code block isn't even needed: `arr.filter(e => !map1[e.id])`